# Is it possible to call RDS DB credentials from Secrets Manager?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an autoscaling group that includes a launch template. In this launch template, I have included user data script to connect to the RDS instance on boot.

Is there a way to securely access RDS instance from the EC2 Autoscaling group?

Many thanks your help!

Extra info

PHP application on EC2 WebServer, it's basically just a simple form that sends data to RDS.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.SecretsManager.SecretsManagerClient.html

Comment: I'm not sure about it is a best practice to connect the RDS instance through the user data. Since you're deploying PHP application, during the startup, you can fetch the secrets from AWS secret manager and try to establish the connection of RDS instance.

Answer (score 0):

The following are some guidelines for accessing RDS securely from EC2:

- Keep traffic within a VPC. RDS should be in a private subnet and EC2 instance(s) should be in private subnets as well
- Lock down security group access. Configure the RDS instance to allow access only from the EC2 instances. I always suggest creating a DB server security group, and then a client security group. The DB server security group (attached to the DB instance) allows access from the client security group (attached to the EC2 instances).
- As `Kumaresh Babu N S` suggested, use secrets manager for storing and retrieving DB credentials. There is also an option for automatically rotating the DB password with secrets manager for an extra layer of security.